# How to add a css class to the first column of a CellTable widget (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.2-celltable

I use a CellTable widget in GWT.

I want to change the font size of every texts contained in the first column. The method `addColumnStyleName` does not fit my need because it adds the class to the `colgroup` tag; only partial css is handled on this tag, and I can't change the font attributes of a colgroup (it has no incidence on text).

So, I want to add a class on each `td` of the first column but cannot find an easy way to do that.

Something like setRowStyles for columns would be fine but it doesn't exist...

Have you got some hint about doing such a thing ?

**EDIT: I use GWT 2.3 and not 2.4 (which has the method setCellStyleNames)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's as easy as calling [`setCellStyleNames`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/Column.html#setCellStyleNames%28java.lang.String%29) on the `Column` instance.

Comment: lol, when you post your answer, I definitively felt stupid to not see it. And I just see that this method is only in 2.4. I use 2.3... So not so stupid ;)

Comment: Except you should definitely update to the latest version of GWT when one gets out ;-)

Comment: I can't use 2.4 for the moment (big app, non regression rules, strict standards...). But I check your answer because this is the best when using 2.4 ;)

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it. But I'm not really happy with that solution. It's a bit verbose for a such simple task. I'm opened to any other suggestion.

The way I achieve it is to create a new cell and a new column :

```
private class KeyColumn extends Column<SimpleLegendItem, String> {

    public KeyColumn() {
        super(new KeyCell());
    }

    @Override
    public String getValue(SimpleLegendItem item) {
        return item.getKey();
    }       
}

private class KeyCell extends AbstractCell<String> {

    @Override
    public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("<span class=\"" + tableResources.cellTableStyle().box() + "\">");
        sb.appendEscaped(value);
        sb.appendHtmlConstant("</span>");
    }       
}
```

To simplify the example, I intentionally do not use a template.

Comment: I was about to propose that solution, or wait for 2.5 and use a `CellTableBuilder`, and then (looking at the code of `DefaultCellTableBuilder`) I found `setCellStyleNames`.